# opencv4android cvcapturefromfile() return NULL

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg

i am using opencv for android in my project. But when i called method cvCreateFileCapture(), it always return NULL. I know this method needs codecs when working in Windows or Linux, So what can i do when i port this method to Android?  Is FFMPEG working?  How can i build opencv4android that using FFMPEG to decode the input video file? Thanks.

these are my codes:

```
//Retrieve data from Java, and construct needed structures or instances
char* filePath = (char*)env->GetStringUTFChars(aviPath, false);

int result=-1;

LOGD(filePath);

CvCapture* pCvCapture = cvCreateFileCapture( filePath );
    //pCvCpature always NULL
if( NULL == pCvCapture)
{
    result = -100;
}
else
{
    cvReleaseCapture( &pCvCapture );
    result = 100;
}

env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(aviPath, filePath);

return (jint)result;
```

Comment: your filePath is a char?

Comment: oh, my bad. Yes you can pratically place the "*" wherever you like... :(